# Python/Pandas select first duplicate in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe df:

```
                 Value
Date     
2021-06-26       7
2021-06-27       3  
2021-06-28       9
2021-06-28       10
```

As you can see, I have two rows with the same index "2021-06-28" but with different values. Now I want to simply select the first row of this duplicate index. In this case:

```
                 Value
Date       
2021-06-28       9
```

I tried the following:

```
duplicateRows = df.loc["2021-06-28"]
firstRow = duplicateRows.iloc[0]
```

However, this gives me the error: "cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid".

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: That code doesn't give that error...

Answer (score 2):

Chain 2 masks - for get first values and also for get all duplicates by [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with inverted mask and with parameter `keep=False` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df.index.duplicated() & df.index.duplicated(keep=False)]
print (df)
            Value
Date             
2021-06-28      9
```